Removing double codes in my headers and column data
I am trying to reader data into Jupyterlab. the challenge I have is that the data has double code around all the fields and the values are in double codes.
I tried removing them via excel. it is tedious task.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AppNameEnd").getOrCreate()
data = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/Big-data-hadoop-and-spark-developer-Project-1--master/Big-data-hadoop-and-spark-developer-Project-1--master/BDH Project 1/BDH Project 1/MarketAnalysisData.csv'


It's unclear to me what you mean by "double code" here. You should include an example of something with the "double code" and an example with it removed, to make it clear what you are trying to achieve here.
